# Run .jar file from Java application and get real-time console output

Tags: java, console

So I'm making a game launcher and need to be able to update my game upon launch. I've been able to check the current version of the game and download the latest version of the .jar. What I need to be able to do is execute the .jar from my launcher and get real-time console output. I know how to display the output but not how to get it from the game. Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: we will need much more info.

Comment: @David Okay what information would you need. Sorry I've only ever posted a few times.

Comment: any code you have tried?

Comment: @DavidHerrero since we last spoke I had managed to achieve what I needed.

Comment: OK, please, write your result in the "answer" section so it can help other users.